# Variables are not passed correctly using list function(?)

Tags: php, post, curl, explode

Here's a snippet I use the gather some data in JSON from a URL specifying 2 variables:

```
<?php

function soldipubblici() {

    $curl_parameters = array(
        'codicecomparto'    =>  "PRO",
        'codiceente'        =>  "011120674",
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://soldipubblici.gov.it/it/ricerca");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query( $curl_parameters ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    ));

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

echo soldipubblici();

?>
```

As you can notice the variables are manually set. So I put up a simple web page with 2 options. The input tag is just for testing the POST data.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Seleziona l'ente</label>
<select name="data" id="data">
    <option value="PRO - 011142764">COMUNE DI AGLIE'</option>
    <option value="PRO - 011120674">COMUNE DI AGRATE CONTURBIA</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
</form>

<script>
$('#data').change(function() {
    $.post("richiesta.php", { value: this.value });
    $('#textfield').val(this.value);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is `richiesta.php`, that receives the POST data on change event (I followed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrYIg.jpg) thread):

```
<?php
list($comparto, $ente) = explode("-", $_POST['value'], 2);
echo "comparto: $comparto, ente: $ente";
?>
```

The request works fine, on change event I successfully get the POST value:

[image]

Since it worked I can now place in richiesta.php my "real" function with the two variables, this time not manually but retrieving the values from the POST request:

```
<?php

function soldipubblici() {
    list($comparto, $ente) = explode("-", $_POST['value'], 2);

    $curl_parameters = array(
        'codicecomparto'    =>  $comparto,
        'codiceente'        =>  $ente,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://soldipubblici.gov.it/it/ricerca");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query( $curl_parameters ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    ));

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
}

echo soldipubblici();

?>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work :(
I get an empty response in Firebug... If in the same snippet I set manually the 2 variables instead if works... seems like they're not passed correctly from the `list` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are spaces around the `-` in the options, you probably need to remove them.

```
$curl_parameters = array(
    'codicecomparto' => trim($comparto),
    'codiceente' => trim($ente),
);
```

Comment: Last thing: how can I modify my jQuery snippet to output the response (that now I can only see through Firebug) in the input box (instead of "this.value")?

Comment: Add a callback function to `$.post()` that does what you want with the response.